# TintRadioButton and TintCheckBox tinting

Tags: android, checkbox, radio-button, material-design

I can't seem to change the `normalState` of `TintCheckBox`, but the check state has the right tint. Right now i am going with this strategy, 
Make a `ColorSelector` and apply in on `android:backgroundTint`. But this isn't working as required.

Is there any way I can style my `TintCheckBox` and `TintRadioButton` ? for different states as in pressed, focused etc.

P.S The solution needs to work for 4+ API level.